# Is there any reason to have more than one globally accessible Mutex?

Tags: ruby

Just started experimenting with threads, and I was wondering: Is there a situation where using more than one Mutex makes sense?

I know Mutex#synchronize is used to lock values, preventing race conditions. I'm using it kinda like this:

```
# class variable
@semaphore = Mutex.new

# in thread in method
self.class.semaphore.synchronize{ x += 1 }
```

Is this a good way to approach locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Here's a rule of thumb: Always use one mutex for each group of variables. For example, use one mutex for an array and a counter of it's elements that are always used together. If two different objects (or groups of objects) can be used by two different threads at different times logically and without destroying your program, give them different mutexes.

## Example

Take this situation with one mutex:

```
$counter1 = 0
$counter2 = 0
$mutex = Mutex.new #Just one mutex
threads = []
threads << Thread.new do 
  $mutex.syncronize do
    3.times do |i|
      sleep(1) #some calculation
      $counter1 += i
    end
  end
end
threads << Thread.new do 
  $mutex.syncronize do
    3.times do |i|
      sleep(1) #some calculation
      $counter2 += i * 3
    end
  end
end
threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

Here are the time values:

```
real    0m6.019s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
```

(low user and sys because of sleep)

Here's a version with two mutexes:

```
$counter1 = 0
$counter2 = 0
$mutex1 = Mutex.new 
$mutex2 = Mutex.new
threads = []
threads << Thread.new do 
  $mutex1.syncronize do
    3.times do |i|
      sleep(1) #some calculation
      $counter1 += i
    end
  end
end
threads << Thread.new do 
  $mutex2.syncronize do
    3.times do |i|
      sleep(1) #some calculation
      $counter2 += i * 3
    end
  end
end
threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

And the time values:

```
real    0m3.021s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.004s
```

That's a x2 increase in speed, because we removed the lock condition that was forcing the two threads to wait on each other, effectively removing any benefit of threading in the first case. Obviously, one mutex per variable is a big increase in efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it makes sense if you have two objects, **A** and **B**, each of which can be used independently. If thread1 wants exclusive access to **A**, and thread2 wants exclusive access to **B**, thread1 and thread2 need not wait for each other. So **A** has a semaphore and **B** has a different semaphore. But be careful! You can get deadlocks when, say, thread1 has **A** and waits to acquire **B** while thread2 has **B** and waits to acquire **A**.

There is a lot of material out there covering shared resources, deadlocks, and the like.